# Conclusions I can draw from the given conditions about a sequence $\{a_n\}^\infty_\mathrm{n=1}$ in the real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Say that $\{a_n\}^\infty_\mathrm{n=1}$ is a sequence of real numbers so that for all odd $n$, $a_n \in (0, 1)$ and for all even $n$, $a_n \not\in (0, 1)$.

Say we also know that for some $L \in \mathbb{R}$, $lim_\mathrm{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n) = L$.

I'm trying to figure out what I can conclude from this and why. (Assuming undergraduate knowledge of real analysis)

It looks like we know that a limit for this sequence exists in the real numbers, hence the sequence is convergent.

Convergent sequences are bounded by definition?

Any thoughts for what I should be seeing from this?

EDIT: As a commenter pointed out, if considering subsequences, then we know that the subsequential limits of a convergent sequence are all the same. (Or stated: Subsequences of a convergent sequence are convergent)

Comment: Have you ever heard about subsequences ? limit points ?

Comment: I'm familiar with limit points, but am uncertain what you're seeing from the problem that would involve them. (I updated the problem to include details of my math background).

Comment: Well, consider the subsequence consisting of the odd terms, and the subsequence consisting of the even terms. Since the sequence converges to $L$, what can you say about these two subsequences ? Since the first one has its values in $(0,1)$, what can you say about its potential limit ? Since the second one has its values outside $(0,1)$, what can you say about its potential limit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$lim_\mathrm{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n) = L$

As $(a_{2n+1}) \in(0, 1) $

Then, $\lim (a_{2n+1})=L \in [0, 1]$

As $(a_{2n}) \notin(0, 1) $

Then, $\lim (a_{2n})=L \in (-\infty,0]\cup [1,\infty)$

Hence, only choice for $L=0, 1$.

Hence, the sequence $(a_n)$ with the property  $(a_n) \in (0, 1)$ for even $n$ and $ (a_n )\notin (0, 1)$  otherwise, must converge to $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Why downvote? It's okay to downvote but please leave a comment so that j can identify my mistake and this will also help me to improve. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The limit of $a_n$ has to belong to the closure of $(0,1)$, which is $[0,1]$, and also to the closure of its complement, which is $(-\infty,0] \cup [1,\infty)$. What can you deduce about the limit, then?